# Gmail-API Giving HttpError 400 Precondition Fails midway of batch fetch emails

Tags: python, python-3.x, gmail, gmail-api

I written the code last year to fetch emails from the night before to the early morning without any issues. Lately I've been receiving the error randomly in middle of fetching emails:

```
Error: <HttpError 400 when requesting https://gmail.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages/blah?format=full&alt=json returned "Precondition check failed.". Details: "[{'message': 'Precondition check failed.', 'domain': 'global', 'reason': 'failedPrecondition'}]">, cannot fetch message
```

and when clicking the URL link I will get:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 401,
    "message": "Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Login Required.",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "required",
        "location": "Authorization",
        "locationType": "header"
      }
    ],
    "status": "UNAUTHENTICATED",
    "details": [
      {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo",
        "reason": "CREDENTIALS_MISSING",
        "domain": "googleapis.com",
        "metadata": {
          "method": "caribou.api.proto.MailboxService.GetMessage",
          "service": "gmail.googleapis.com"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

This doesn't make sense to me when the code below can fetch some messages midway without issue.

Below is the code I have:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import sqlite3
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import pytz
import base64
import logging
import time
import pendulum
import os.path

from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials
from googleapiclient.discovery import build

from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow

def get_decode_body(payload):
    if "parts" not in payload:
        return ""
    email_content = ""
    for part in payload["parts"]:
        if part["mimeType"] == "text/plain":
            data = part["body"]["data"]
            email_content += base64.urlsafe_b64decode(data).decode("utf-8")
        else:
            email_content += get_decode_body(part)
    return email_content

def get_msg_date(message):
    return datetime.fromtimestamp(float(message["internalDate"]) / 1000.0).astimezone(pytz.timezone("US/Eastern"))

def check_date_boundary(message, str_date, end_date):
    dt = get_msg_date(message)
    return str_date <= dt and end_date >= dt

def get_subject(message):
    headers = message["payload"]["headers"]
    # checks for empty subject
    subject_list = [i['value'] for i in headers if i["name"]=="Subject"]
    subject = "".join(subject_list)
    return subject

def convert_to_datetime(time_string):
    TIME_FORMAT = "%y%m%d %H:%M"
    return datetime.strptime(time_string, TIME_FORMAT).astimezone(pytz.timezone("US/Eastern"))

# used to just call Gmail API
class Gmail:

    def __init__(self, token_file):
        # The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
        # created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
        # time
        creds = None
        if os.path.exists(token_file):
            creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file(token_file, ['https://mail.google.com/'])
        # If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
        if not creds or not creds.valid:
            if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
                print("LOGGER: token invalid, refreshing for new token")
                creds.refresh(Request())
            else:
                print("LOGGER: re-credentialing due to token not found")
                flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                    'credentials.json', ['https://mail.google.com/'])
                creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
            # Save the credentials for the next run
            with open('token.json', 'w') as token:
                token.write(creds.to_json())

        self.service = build('gmail', 'v1', credentials=creds, cache_discovery=False)

    def get_all_messages(self, start_dt, end_dt, page_token = None):
        # Gmail does not give results when before and after dates are the same, edate=edate+1 will be fine for 9 to 9:20 run
        # Padding is done on sdate/edate to account for utc time difference when calling Gmail API query
        sdate = start_dt.date()-timedelta(days=1)
        edate = end_dt.date()+timedelta(days=1)

        messages_out = []

        # loop is based on page_token, first and last page of search query is 0 but between that there is #
        while True:
            results = self.service.users().messages().list(userId='me', includeSpamTrash=True, q='before:%s, after:%s' % (edate, sdate), pageToken=page_token, maxResults=45).execute()

            message_ids = results.get('messages', [])
            messages = []
            def add(id, msg, err):
                # id is given because this will not be called in the same order
                if err:
                    raise Exception("Error: %s, cannot fetch message" % (err))
                else:
                    # print(f"LOGGER: append msg id {msg['id']} to list of messages")
                    messages.append(msg)

            page_token = results["nextPageToken"] if "nextPageToken" in results else None
            batch = self.service.new_batch_http_request()
            print("LOGGER: creating new batch http request")
            for i, msg in enumerate(message_ids):
                #print(f"LOGGER: getting message {i} by id {msg['id']} and adding to batch request")
                batch.add(self.service.users().messages().get(userId='me', id=msg['id'], format='full'), callback=add)
            print("LOGGER: executing batch request")
            batch.execute()
            time.sleep(1)
            # fetching batch of message based on current page_token

            if not messages:
                print('LOGGER: No messages found.')
            else:
                criteria = '(SINCE "' + start_dt.strftime("%d-%b-%Y") + '")'
                print(f"LOGGER: {str(datetime.now())} - Page at {criteria}")

                # getting subject, decoded body message, timestamp of message, and the message ID
                for message in messages:
                    if check_date_boundary(message, start_dt, end_dt):
                        try:
                            body_decoded = get_decode_body(message["payload"])
                        except Exception as e:
                            print("LOGGER: Error decoding message", message)
                            raise e
                        subject = get_subject(message)
                        dt = get_msg_date(message)
                        messages_out.append({"subject": subject, "message": body_decoded, "datetime": dt, "msg_id": message["id"]})

            if page_token is None:
                break
        # messages_out contain all message items from all the pages
        return messages_out

token_path = os.path.join("/home/user/", "token.json")
gmail = Gmail(token_path)
start_dt = convert_to_datetime("240117 16:00")
end_dt = convert_to_datetime("240118 9:00")
print(gmail.get_all_messages(start_dt, end_dt))
```

Things I've already attempted:

- re-authenticate with new token
- manually expiring the token.json
- double check my API secrets
- reduced maxResults less than 50 to avoid quota limit per second
  https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/quota

My current library versions:

- google-api-python-client 2.114.0
- google-auth              2.16.1
- google-auth-httplib2     0.2.0
- google-auth-oauthlib     1.2.0

The problem is so random that the code will work 1/10th of the time and suddenly it works 100% at the next hour.

Answer (score 0):

So apparently having 800,000+ emails in inbox will somehow create issues with authenticating via API. After deleting most of the emails the 400 precondition seems to occur a lot less but once in a while will still re-occur.